# Retrieving all employee and Managers in a java Web Application through ADFS

Tags: spring-boot, adfs

Is it possible to connect to ADFS and obtain a list of all Employee email addresses and Managers etc. programmatically

Answer (score 0):

No, ADFS is only for a single authenticated user.

For a single user, you could use the query command as described [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tips-and-tricks-with-adfs-claims-rules-b0b3d910f804). Just search for "query".

To do what you require, you need to use the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) methods, e.g. for C#, see [here](https://www.codemag.com/article/1312041/Using-Active-Directory-in-.NET).